# How to create a initiate a CSS transitioned event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code which draws a circle on the screen using the css transition, when the transition is finished, it triggers something else. In the code below the transitioned event doesn't work.

Part1: css

```
<style>
    .circle {
      transition-property: width, height;
      transition-duration: 2s;
      position: fixed;
      left = 100px;
      top  = 100px;       
      background-color: red;
      border-radius: 50%;        
    } 
  </style>
```

Part2: Javascript:

```
 <script >  
    function changeRadius(radius) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');   
  div.className = 'circle';  
  document.body.append(div);

  div.style.width = div.style.height = 0;
  console.log(div.style.width);

  div.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {            
    alert('transitionend event!');
  });  

  div.style.width = div.style.height = 2 * radius + 'px'; 
  console.log(div.style.width);       
}

changeRadius(100);
```

The 'transitioned event' is not triggered even if the 'console.log' showed the 'width' property of div has changed to 200px. I have to wrap the last part in the  setTimeout function as below:

```
setTimeout(() => {
 div.style.width = div.style.height = 2 * radius + 'px';             
}, 0);
```

Now it works!

May someone knows the inner logic behind this. My assumption is:  when the code is implemented, even if the style property inside a function changes, it's not considered as a transitioned event. However,  the code outside this block to change the style property will work, such as 'setTimeout' or 'mouse hover' etc. I would like to get some deeper interpretation of this!

Comment: there is an error in your CSS use  (:) instead of (=) for left and top CSS property.

Comment: Good question... I tried changing the width in a callback function but that too didn't trigger the 'transition' even though the width had clearly changed... it worked only with setTimeout, even though it was 0...

Comment: @VikasJadhav yes, I've made that mistake , thanks. But still it doesn't help to solve this problem.